# Confusion about Google OAuth packages in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I need to access some Google APIs (via `Google.Apis.*` NuGet Packages). Therefore I need to use the [`Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore) package as described in the
[official documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started#2.-authorized-api-access-oauth-2.0):

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(o =>
    {
        o.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleOpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        o.DefaultForbidScheme = GoogleOpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        o.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddGoogleOpenIdConnect(options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = googleClientId;
        options.ClientSecret = googleClientSecret;
    });
```

On the other hand, I use classical ASP.NET Core Identity, especially the [Google external login setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins)
using the
[`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google) NuGet package which is initialized like this:

```
services
    .AddAuthentication()
    .AddGoogle(options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = googleClientId;
        options.ClientSecret = googleClientSecret;
    });
```

Is there a way to share the OAuth configurations, logins, ...?  Both packages use their own OAuth intialization code...  Will I face problems calling both `AddGoogle()` and `AddGoogleOpenIdConnect()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Background info

Authorization is [OAuth2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749).  You would use it for example to request access to a users google drive account.  Once you have been granted access you would be given a refresh token and you would be able to access the users data when ever you need.

[Open id connect](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html) its authentication or login. It tells you that a user is in fact logged in it doesn't give you access to more then the users profile information by default.

## Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore

Strictly speaking the Google APIs library normally only gave you access to authorization.  However `Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore` does add an open id connect component to to the authentication in the form of `AddGoogleOpenIdConnect` which will give you both authentication and authorization at the same time.

## Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google

Is as its states Authentication or login. The user is logging in and authenticating that they are currently accessing your application.

## recap

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google` only gives you authentication or login,  while `Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore` will potentially give you login and authorization.

## Adding both

TBH I question why you would add both.  Technically if you did and they didn't bash heads with each other which they might.  You may end up with a double login. As these two libraries will both be trying to Authenticate the user.  You will need two access tokens one for each library.  I'm not sure if they set different cookies or not if they set the same cookie then they will reset each other cookies causing the user to need to login or authorize the application again to reset the cookie for each library you are trying to use.

Not to mention what adding [Authorize] attribute to a method is going to do how will it know which one to pick if your adding to authorization forms

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the confusion.